# How to create TableView using RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I create a TableView in android using RecyclerView, Can it be achieved using GridLayoutManager? Is there any solution mentioned on any website, I searched and I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: interested in the same question. Did you found a good lead on how to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only limited number of columns which can be displayed with in the available screen space, you can use the `GridLayoutManager`. An image gallery is a perfect example for this use case.

If you have a huge number of columns, you have to create another `RecyclerView` with Horizontal scrolling inside the `bindViewHolder` method of the the main `RecyclerView`. This is still efficient as it uses `RecyclerView` under the hood.